# Alterar css de templates

Tags: html, css

Esse [Site](http://www.saichorao.com.br/) é baseado em template e tenho acesso ao [CSS dele](http://www.saichorao.com.br/css/style.css); porém estou tentando mudar a cor do fundo (Toda parte branca - Conforme imagens anexas) e não localizo no css onde mudar... Com isso, gostaria de ajudar para mudar as partes conforme supracitadas.[image: Imagem 1][image: Imagem 2][image: Imagem 3]

Comment: Votando para fechar e negativando porque esta pergunta **não vai ajudar ninguém no futuro**. Legal que consertou sua dúvida, mas não é o tipo de pergunta útil aqui...

Comment: Então explique como deleta-la... Não serve pra mais ninguém mesmo, assim não aparece outros pra dar downvotes. Obrigado!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Na página de "contato" pelo que vi a classe responsável pela cor clara é essa

```
#wrapper #main {
  font-family: 'PT Sans Narrow', sans-serif;
  background-color: #f8f7f0;
}
```

Basta alterar o **#f8f7f0** para a cor desejada.

O link "chaves cruzadas" creio que seja a mesma classe acima. Faz a alteração na cor do background e veja se deu certo.

Comment: Acessei o seu CSS e continua a mesma cor do background

Comment: Caro colega, peço desculpas... A sua resposta estava correta... Testei em casa porém não tinha funcionado; testei agora aqui no trabalho e deu certo; então acessei meu pc de casa e limpei o navegador e testei novamente e deu certo; meu navegador estava com cache cheio e afins. Logico que agora retornei ao normal, e mais tarde coloco a cor desejada; mas de qualquer forma já marquei a resposta como correta.